# Category Name input field

Tags: category, overrides, category-tree

The category name input field is a required field * but is there a way to save it without a category name?

I see the elements here:

```
<div class="admin__field-control" data-bind="css: {'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip, '_with-reset': $data.showFallbackReset &amp;&amp; $data.isDifferedFromDefault}">
        <!-- ko ifnot: hasAddons() --><!-- ko template: elementTmpl -->
<input class="admin__control-text" type="text" data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled,
            maxlength: 255
    }" name="name" aria-describedby="notice-TSAJULD" id="TSAJULD" maxlength="255">
<!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: hasAddons() --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.tooltip --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: error --><label class="admin__field-error" data-bind="attr: {for: uid}, text: error" for="TSAJULD">This is a required field.</label><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.notice --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.additionalInfo --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.hasService() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

Any way to get around adding the Category Name.. I have an image that i want to add instead of the category name.

Second question is... it renders an html page

mynewcategorypage.html

Where is this stored?

Would it be better to remove the validation, can i remove the validation? I notice sometimes in the URL rewrites that there is a request path but no target path.. how was that achieved? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify in Content > Design > Configuration: Edit > HTML HEAD > Scripts and style sheets.

There just use some css and target the `.category .page-title-wrapper .page-title {display:none}`

Comment: Thank you @thismethod that worked for me perfectly.